# What unit of time does this Lua code measure?

Tags: time, lua, duration

Can someone advise what unit of time `t_duration` is in, below:

```lua
local timer = os.clock()
 
*insert script here*
 
t_duration = string.format("%.9f", os.clock() - timer)
```

I am getting conflicting answers elsewhere.

Have been unable to test properly myself.

Comment: Conflicting answers from where? The docs say os.clock returns seconds. If timer is also in seconds, then your answer is "seconds." If not, then the answer is "nothing meaningful."

Comment: Conflicting information from a senior colleague who's been working on LUA far longer than myself. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: See https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time called os.clock() in timer will be substracted from the actual os.clock() in t_duration with a constant format of 9 digits after the floatingpoint.
In short: It will be measure the runtime of `*insert script here*` in seconds as a floatingpoint converted to a string with string.format()

PS: "seconds" is not a integer it will be a floatingpoint number
Example:

```
> print(os.clock())
1.892664
> print(string.format("%.9f", os.clock()))
1.911050000
```

With Lua i learned a new Datatype: HEX FLOAT

```
> print(string.format("%a", os.clock()))
0x1.f96638433d6c7p+0
> print(0x1.f96638433d6c7p+0)
1.974216
```